# How to map by default to a queue with yarn?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

How can we map to a default queue all the jobs that came from users that their group name is different than the queues names?

Using yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings we know we can use:

```
<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings</name>
    <value>u:user2:%primary_group</value>
    <description>user2 is mapped to queue name same as primary group</description>
 </property>
```

or

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings</name>
    <value>g:group1:queue2</value>
    <description>group1 is mapped to queue2</description>
 </property>
```

BUT What happen if my user group has not a queue with the same name? How can I map all these jobs to a default queue?

Answer (score 1):

Using the second option mentioned `g:group1:queue2`, it is not mandatory that user group name and queue name should be same. Leaving that, I think the question is more about how to map a user to a `default` queue when none of the user group membership matches for a queue. Here are the options

1. If a `yarn.root.default` queue is defined, it will get submitted to that.
2. Else you can define a default queue, assume the queue name is `my_default_queue` and define a mapping as a last option for property `yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings`

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings</name>
    <value>g:group1:queue2,u:%user:my_default_queue</value>
 </property>
```

Make sure you define the default mapping as last option, so that it will be checked when none of the preceding mapping succeeds.